# Criteria API. Достать объект с ближайшей датой и уникальным provider.id

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Этот метод достает строчку, помеченную булевым флагом как true. Соответственно при создании новой записи, флаг в ней устанавливается в true, у записи предыдущей флаг меняется на false. Хочу от этого избавиться, как через criteria доставать запись с крайней, ближней к настоящему моменту времени, запись? Подскажите пожалуйста, за ранее спасибо

```
public ProviderBalance findLastByProvider(Long providerId){
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
    eq(criteria, "provider.id", providerId);
    eq(criteria, "last", true);
    return uniqueResult(criteria);
}
```

**UPD**
Баланс

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "provider_balance")
public class ProviderBalance extends UndeletableEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", nullable = false)
    private Provider provider;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bunch_id")
    private ProviderPaymentBunch providerPaymentBunch;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id")
    private ProviderTransaction transaction;

    @Column(name = "balance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    public ProviderBalance() {}
}
```

Провайдер

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "provider")
 @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
 public class Provider extends BaseEntity {

     @Column(name = "exported_id")
     private String exportedId;

     @Column(name = "exported_at")
     private Instant exportedAt;

     @Column(name = "code", unique = true, nullable = false)
     private String code;

     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     @Column(name = "legal_type", nullable = false)
     private ProviderLegalType legalType;

     public Provider() {}
}
```

**UPD2**

Баланс наследует UndeletableEntity. UndeletableEntity в свою очередь наследует BaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    public static final int BATCH_SIZE = 500;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdAt = Instant.now();
}
```

Comment: Можно отсортировать по дате и вернуть первый элемент выборки. Можно отсортировать по дате и лимитировать выборку одним элементом. Можно использовать агрегатную функцию для выборки элемента с максимальной датой. И лучше перейти на JPA Criteria API.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, спасибо за ответ. Воспользовался одним из вариантов. Но тут же опять загвоздка. Необходимо достать балансы по всем провайдерам, в то же время эти записи должны быть крайними по дате создания. Наведите на мысль пожалуйста, за ранее спасибо

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть код сущностей, участвующих в выборке.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, upd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде должно получиться:

```
session.createCriteria(ProviderBalance.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("provider")
    .add(Projections.max("createdAt"))
  ).list();
```

Проверить, к сожалению, сейчас не могу.

Comment: Сергей спасибо, а что такое providerId? Это входной параметр? если да, то у меня нет этого параметра, вот метод                                    
public List<ProviderBalance> findAllLast() 
.add(Restrictions.eq("p.id", providerId)) - эта строчка лишняя получается? Сейчас попробую

Comment: И правда, лишняя.

Comment: метод работает, уникальность и крайность даты выдерживаются, но дату Вы взяли по провайдеру, возможно я не уточнил, дата нужна по балансу)

Comment: И возвращает массив Object размером 2(Provider  и его поле Instant)

Comment: Не вижу в сущности `ProviderBalance` поля типа `Date`.

Comment: UPD2 добавил в тему

Comment: Тогда ещё проще.

Comment: Вроде работает, но почему возвращает массив полей баланса но не сам объект?

Comment: Потому, что проекция может возвращать больше или меньше полей, чем есть в класса сущности, а значит нельзя будет преобразовать их в экземпляр сущности. Вам может помочь метод [setResultTransformer()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer)).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Что если достать запись с самым большим id?

```java
public ProviderBalance findLastByProvider() {
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(ProviderBalance.class);
    c.addOrder(Order.desc("provider.id"));
    c.setMaxResults(1);
    return (ProviderBalance) c.uniqueResult();
}
```